# Push forward of a vector field on the tangent bundle TM onto M under the bundle projection map

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle, pushforward

Given the tangent bundle $\pi:TM \rightarrow M$, a generic vector field $X \in T_{0}^{1}(TM)$ can be written in local coordinates as:
\begin{equation}
X = A^a(x,v)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} + B^a(x,v)\frac{\partial}{\partial v^a}.
\end{equation}
The (smooth) projection function $\pi$ induces a map $T\pi:TTM\rightarrow TM$, defined pointwise as $(T\pi)(X):=\pi_*X$, where $X$ is to be interpreted as a *point* in $TTM$ on the left hand side, and as the corresponding *vector* at the point $(x,v)\in TM$ on the right hand side.

Now, my problem is: if $X$ is a vector *field* on $TM$, does $\pi_*X$ define a vector *field* on $M$?

It seems to me that this is only possible if
\begin{equation}
X = A^a(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} + B^a(x,v)\frac{\partial}{\partial v^a}.
\end{equation}
that is if $A^a$ does not depend on $v$. In that case, $\pi_*X=A^a(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$, which is a well-defined vector field on M.

Nonetheless, in all the manuals I have consulted this point is not discussed at all and it is simply stated that $\pi\circ\pi_{TM} = \pi\circ T\pi$, where $\pi_{TM}$ is the projection map of the second tangent bundle $\pi_{TM}:TTM\rightarrow TM$.

Any insight?

Comment: You are absolutely right, not all vector fields on $TM$ are projectable and, locally, your condition $A^a(x,v)=A^a(x)$ is precisely what is needed.

Comment: @WishYouTheBest, thank you for your comment.